# Error EXC_BAD_ACCESS and unrecognised selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I managed to integrate my apps with Linkedin using a library downloaded from internet. I succeeded with it in two projects but now I'm trying to integrate it with my new app but I'am receiving this error message. There is the same classes I use in those two projects that works well.

What should I check ? I'm struggling since yesterday but with no results.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The `aURL` parameter is really a `NSURL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're passing in an `NSSet` instead of an `NSURL` (based on the error message `reason: '-[NSCFSet absoluteURL: unrecognized selector sent to instance`). Without seeing more of your code, I would set a breakpoint on the crashing line and check out where your code is passing in an `NSSet` as an `NSURL`.

Something to always be wary of is that Objective C (like C) is weakly-typed, meaning something like `NSString *notAString = @YES;` will compile and run despite obviously being wrong. Observe that if you try to ask this "string" for its length, your program will crash with an error much like the one you're seeing above.

Comment: You are my hero. That NSURL were null when it arrives in the method. Fortunately it stores a constant URL so I had just to replace it with the string I need. I will investigate why it was arriving null and in the others projects it was ok.

Comment: Are you sure a null URL was the problem? One really unique feature of Objective C is the way it handles null objects – specifically, sending a message to a null object just returns null instead of throwing an exception or crashing like almost every other language. The error in your question looks like the object had a value, just not the type of value the crashing function expected.

Comment: I think the problem was generated by the fact that the URL variable was declared inside brackets directly after the @interface. I made it a property and my problem got resolved. After that, I realized the class had -fno-objc-arc compiler flag though it was using ARC.